# The difference between $X^{\ast}$ and $X^*$?

Tags: symbols, lyx, typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\star vs. \ast in formulas. Which one to use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82155/star-vs-ast-in-formulas-which-one-to-use)

What is the difference between `X^{\ast}` and `X^*` ?

Both look the same in the pdf file - although when using Lyx the former looks in the "internal", pre-compilation display  of Lyx nicer.

Is it better (any reason - like "compatibility" in the future) to prefer one over the other? (In typing speed, the latter is obviously better to use.)

Comment: You should have a look at [this thread](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82155/star-vs-ast-in-formulas-which-one-to-use).

Comment: @Corentin oops sorry I should have known about that one (seeing as I gave an identical answer:-)

Comment: I like putting it this way: an <\ast> is a more sophisticated version of a <*>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

$X^{\ast}$

$ X^*$

\end{document}
```

shows

```
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 X
....\kern0.7847
....\hbox(3.25694+0.0)x4.59723, shifted -3.62892
.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/7 ^^C
....\mathoff
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 5.11414
...\hbox(6.88586+0.0)x345.0, glue set 316.33334fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 X
....\kern0.7847
....\hbox(3.25694+0.0)x4.59723, shifted -3.62892
.....\OMS/cmsy/m/n/7 ^^C
```

which confirms they are in fact the same character (^^C from 7pt cmsy font)

The setting comes from `fontmath.ltx` which is part of the source of the latex format which has:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ast}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{*}{\mathbin}{symbols}{"03} % \ast
```