# \star printing as \ast

Tags: symbols

I would like to use both `\star` and `\ast` in my document, but they produce the same character (*), whether or not `\star` is in math mode.  I am using pdflatex in MikTeX 2.9 with the `times` package.  What package do I need to get the `\star` character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82155/star-vs-ast-in-formulas-which-one-to-use .  Or at least you'll find some answers there...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: @longtom -- this symbol is identified in the comprehensive symbols list as being a "basic" symbol, so a user should expect it to be present.  since it is not present with the `times` package, what is needed is the mechanism for actually accessing it, and that isn't provided by the linked question.

Comment: I get two different symbols from `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{times}\begin{document}$\star\ast$\end{document}`. Can you show a minimal example?

Answer (score 4):

Computer modern has a star symbol. Since it is a rather stylistic symbol let's use it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}    
    \newcommand{\mystar}{{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont$\star$}}

    Foo\mystar bar*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or, much more efficiently, `\renewcommand{\star}{{\usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}\symbol{63}}}`