# Difference between \ast and *

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

As far as I can tell, writing `\ast` and `*` yield the same latex output.  Are there any subtle differences between these two symbols?  Are there any reasons to prefer one over the other?  Do they produce literally the same output or are the symbols slightly different in some fonts?  Is one or the other compatible with more latex compilers?  Does their interchangeability depend on being in math mode, or not being in math mode?

Comment: see [the first answer to this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82155/star-vs-ast-in-formulas-which-one-to-use) . They are the same

Comment: In math mode, `\ast` and `*` are interchangeable.